# Is Cross Site journaling acceptable in Exchange 2010/2013?

Tags: exchange-2010

We need to have messages journal in one AD site, be delivered in another.

Formerly, in E2003, this was an issue (or caused issues) due to how the transport bifucates messages.

Is anyone aware of any issues, or guidance that would lead me to pursue this (easier) or find an alternate solution (harder/more costly)?